# Detect Wifi SSID in Xamarin MAC application

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.mac

I have a xamarin.MAC application built using Xamarin.MAC. Now I need to find a way to get the connected Wifi SSID in MAC application. I see lot of solution for xamarin.ios.But couldn't see the solution for MAC Application. Do any one know how can I detect SSID in the Xamarin.MAC application?

Thanks in Advance

Roshil

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `CoreWLan` framework, something like this will get you started:

```
var client = CWWiFiClient.SharedWiFiClient;
foreach (var @interface in client.Interfaces) // you can have multiple wifi devices connected at once
{
    if (@interface.DeviceAttached)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(@interface.Ssid);
    }
}
```

re: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corewlan/cwwificlient